# Triggering simultaneous transitions with D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have built a D3 script [(click here for jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/uxy8d9vs/7/) that connects nodes with paths. As you can see from the fiddle, I have created a transition that sends a circle from node A to node C.

I now want to amend the script as follows:

1. Send 10 blue/red circles from A to B in 10 seconds
2. Send 15 blue/red circles from A to C in 10 seconds
3. Steps (1) and (2) are simultaneous
4. Circle dispatch is 'random'. Circle speed does not vary but dispatch is triggered unevenly across different paths, color and the 10 seconds. More than one circle can be on a path at once.

Steps 1 to 4 can of course be saved in an array, like so:

```
{
  "pathAB": {
    "duration": 1000,
    "blue": 5,
    "red":5
  },
  "pathAC": {
    "duration": 1000,
    "blue": 5,
    "red":10
  }
}
```

I am stuck. At the moment I can't even fire two sequential events (the second overrides the first, and the first is not triggered). Efforts to fire simultaneous events also failed. I have been scanning stack overflow all evening with limited success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How exactly are you trying to implement this? You can certainly just run the transitions in parallel on the different elements.

Comment: Hello Lars! Thank you for your message. The jsFiddle referenced is my latest attempt.. I am not able to run the transitions in parallel on the different elements. I think if you could show me how to do just that, using my example, that would already be a big step forward for me in terms of solving my issue. If you really can't have two circles transitioning on the same path at once, I assume I could superimpose multiple paths to achieve the desired effect??

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. All you need to do is transition a second circle: http://jsfiddle.net/uxy8d9vs/9

Comment: Lars, this is a massive step forward for me. I (think) you have significantly increased my understanding of how D3 works and how I can use it going forward. My question now is as follows : right now the two markers are traveling along the same path. That is because the animation script at the bottom specifies path "AC". Would I need to write a separate transition script for each arc? I am asking because the markers so far do not specify the arc on which they are supposed to transition. How would I get a third circle travelling on arc "AB", for example?

Comment: You just need to specify a different path in the transition... http://jsfiddle.net/uxy8d9vs/10

Comment: Lars, you evidently got this to work and I am very grateful. I am however very confused. Where is the bit of code that assigns marker to path AC and the bit of code that assigns marker1 to path AB? Or do the transitions run in the order that the markers are announced? I thought I was relatively experienced with Javascript but am finding D3 hugely counterintuitive, for a reason. Your help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Ok, did you write the jsfiddle yourself or did you copy it from somewhere else? If the latter, I suggest that first you try to understand what's going on there. This will answer all your questions.

Comment: Lars, this jsfiddle I have been working on for two days. My contribution was to adapt Bostock's 'follow the path' script with another script that uses a force layout to bind nodes with paths. I am learning and am grateful for your help. As mentioned I am finding D3 counterintuitive. Also, as implied by my name, I am a bit of a noob.

Comment: Ok, I would still suggest you try to understand what exactly is happening. You have code in there that explicitly links the elements that move and the path, so it should be easy to find.

Comment: Sure, let me dig around a little more. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Lars -your feedback and input has allowed me to resolve my issue. If you would like to reformulate as an answer I would be glad to tick it off for you. I am very grateful for your help. I worked it out in the end :)

Comment: As an exercise, why don't you try to formulate an answer yourself? I'm sure that will help others much more as you can explain what the issues were. The solution seemed obvious to me :)